# Probability, atleast case, minimum length, random no

Tags: probability

This isn't homework. I am not able to proceed.  Please help.

A software function generates a random number $N$ digits long. Each digit is determined by randomly selecting a value from $0$ through $9$. All ten values are equally likely, and different digits may have the same value. Determine the minimum length $N$ such that there is at least a $50\%$ probability that at least one digit will have the value $0$.

Comment: Homework or not, you really should show some of your *own work*; even if it is just thoughts about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that each digit is non-zero is $9/10$. So the probability that none of the digits are zero is $0.9^N$. You want that to be less than $0.5$:
$$
0.9^N<0.5\implies N\log(0.9)<\log(0.5)\implies N>\frac{\log(0.5)}{\log(0.9)}\approx6.6 
$$
So minimum $N$ is $7$.